# AngularJS / Gulp / Router : CSS not found when changing routes

Tags: css, angularjs, gulp, angular-routing

I have a router like this:

```
var mainmodule.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/home',{
       templateUrl:'src/home/home.html'
    };
    $routeProvider.when('/home/sports',{
       templateUrl:'src/home/sports.html'
    }
})
```

The redirections work great.
The problem is that in my main file (index.html), I have the following `css` in the head declaration:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
```

If I reload the page at `localhost:8080/home` the styles are correctly loaded.
But, I reload the page at `localhost:8080/home/sports` the styles are not found as he tries to load `localhost:8080/home/css/main.css` instead of `localhost:8080/css/main.css`.

Is there a configuration I missed to tell the `routeProvider` to maintain the original css path ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

use relative to root path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css"/>
```